# How can i use an if statement in a mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a mongodb collection named Feed and it has an attribute named "type". according to that string, i want to send a changeable fields with json. For example if type is "photo" i want to do somethig like that

```
 schema.find({number: "123456"},"body number",
 function(err, data) {
```

but if the string is story, instead of photo; İn the same 'schema.find' query,it should create a json with "body url" instead of "body number". and they all should be passed with the same json.

```
  res.json(data);
```

For a clear example, i want my json to be like this. as you se the fields change according to "type". but they are all actually in the same collection.

```
[
    {
        type: 'photo',
        number: 123456,
        url: 'asd.jpg',

    },
    {
        type: 'story',
        body: 'hello',
        number: 123456,

    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to return certain documents fields from the Feed collection, which are specified in a variable like e.g. `"firstName pic points photos"`.

Are there Feed documents with the `story` field?

The [Model.find()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-find) does not create any schema.

Maybe edit with further code so we can understand the command.

Answer (score 0):

For document-specific JSON formatting like this, you can override the default `toJSON` method of your `Feed` model as shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1589265).

**UPDATE**

If you want this sort of flexibility in your documents then it's even easier.  Just define your schema to include all possible fields and then only set the fields that apply to given document for its `type`.  The fields that you don't use won't appear in the document (or in the JSON response).  So your schema would look like:

```
var feedSchema = new Schema({
    type: { type: 'String' },
    venue: Number,
    url: String,
    body: String
});
```

Comment: my problem is not with json. according to the type field, i want my fields to change like i showed in the example.for example if the type is photo the other fields must be venue and url or if it is story the other fields should be body and venue.

Comment: i already have this schema. But in my "feed.find" query i have to use some kind of a if statement so that if the type is "photo" i could only use some of the fields of this schema ElSE if the type is "story"  i could use the rest fields. And at the end i want my json to be like i wrote in the example.

Comment: @siemya So you want to alter which fields from the document are included in the data read from the database based on each documents's `type` value?  You can't do that in a `find` query.

Comment: So how can i do it? i should do this operaiton with the schema's which has a venue number 12345.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [mongoose-schema-extend](https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend). Using the 'Discriminator Key' feature, you can instruct .find() to create the proper model in each individual case.

Your code should look like this (not tested):

```
var feedSchema = new Schema({
    venue: Number,
}, {discriminatorKey : 'type' }});

var photoSchema = feedSchema.extend({
    url: String
});
var storySchema = feedSchema.extend({
    body: String
});

var Feed= mongoose.model('feed', feedSchema );
var Photo= mongoose.model('photo', photoSchema );
var Story= mongoose.model('story', storySchema );
//'photo' and 'story' will be the values for 'type' key


Feed.find({venue: "123456"}, function(err, models) {
   console.log(models[0] instanceof Photo); // true
   console.log(models[0] instanceof Story); // false

   console.log(models[1] instanceof Photo); // false
   console.log(models[1] instanceof Story); // true
});
```